# Changing sap ui5 application locale dynamically in the application

Tags: user-interface, localization, sapui5

I have two different language i.e English and German in my web app and user can change the language in application through a select box. Initially i am getting preferred language from the back-end and i am setting locale of the core as follows.

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage("//according to whatever is coming from back-end")
```

Now lets say initial language is English, if user open a control i.e sap.m.datepicker, calendar is being displayed in English. If user changes the language to German from the application i am again changing the language in the core as shown below:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage("de-DE")
```

Now if user opens that same datepicker, it is being displayed in English instead of German and if user opens some another control or datepicker it is being rendered in German.

Page is not getting refreshed while changing the language in app.
Please suggest me a solution to dynamically change the locale of the controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039588/language-switch-in-sapui5/41070360#41070360) helps a little.

The problem is that in many cases, maybe even in most cases, the standard UI5 controls detect the language only once when they get loaded. Very often, the control developers did not implement a "dynamic change" of the language. If you check the link I mentioned above you will see that there are ways to react on language changes, but very often this is not implemented for whatever reason.

However, I'm afraid to tell you that in your case the standard control might not support dynamic language changes out of the box (but I did not check the code). Also, it seems that the UI5 guys at SAP do not consider this as a bug (see this [github issue](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1258)). Such a pity...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `sap.ui.core.Core.attachLocalizationChanged(fnFunction, oListener)` and add this to the `onInit` function of your controller.

From this, in your `fnFunction` rebuild the controls where you require the locale changes to be dynamic.

example:

```
onInit: function(oEvent) {
    sap.ui.getCore().attachLocalizationChanged(this._handleLocalizationChanged, this);
},
_handleLocalizationChanged: function() {
    // ... Some logic to re-build / set locale for the dynamic controls.
}
```

This is my interpretation of what should be done based on the information in the [api](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Configuration.html#setLanguage)