# Can't change an app localization during the lifetime

Tags: sapui5

As far as I know, UI5 determines the wanted localization based on browser's HTTP header `accept-language`  with respect of `supportedLocales` and `fallbackLocale` values of the `manifest.json` app descriptor.

In my case, however, initially user sees an authorization dialog in English and after authorization I would like set an app localization based on a user config, loaded upon successful authorization.

Based on [Language switch in SAPUI5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039588/language-switch-in-sapui5), I've tried to apply:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage("fr");
```

in the view `onInit()` but instead I get a blinked view in the desired localization and then an empty window.

Since `sap.ui.getCore().setLanguage()` [does not guarantee](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Configuration#methods/setLanguage) that already created, language dependent objects will be updated by this call, I've tried `location.reload();` to trigger a complete page reloading and rebuilding all UI5 elements but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My go-to choice is

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().applySettings({
    language: 'de',
});
```

This switches the used i18n bundle.

However, there are still some occurrences that don't get translated e.g. the work-day labels in a `sap.m.PlanningCalendar`, which remain in the browser's language.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this can be done without a reload.

For [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=URLSearchParams), you can use this code to change the URL:

```js
const oURL = new URL(window.location.href);
window.location.href = oURL.searchParams.set("sap-ui-language", "en").toString();
```

If, for some reasons, you have the language already in the URL, you need to add a [cachebreaker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22429796/1960986).

Comment: Although this approach works, it adds `?sap-ui-language=en` to the URL, which I would like ideally to avoid. In addition to _possible_ issues with caching.